# Something about two-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

I am a beginner in C and I am a Chinese.
I want this code that can come to Matrix multiplication.
To achieve this, I use two-dimensional array.
But when I run the code and input matrices, the result of the multiplication is always strange.
However, the code can manage to output the matrices I have input.
So I suppose that the multiplication of two arrays' elements causes trouble.
And thanks to goddess, when I try to output the multiplication of two arrays' elements, it truly comes to the same problem.

According to this, I come up with some questions.

1. How can I successfully achieve the multiplication of two arrays' elements?
2. How can I correct my code?
3. If I have some habits that you cannot stand, you can tell me certainly!

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // insert code here...
    int i, j ,k ;
    int tensu1[4][3],tensu2[3][4],tensu3[4][4];

    /*input the element of the matrix*/
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            printf("请输入第一个矩阵第%d行第%d列的数： ", i+1 , j+1);
            scanf( "%d" , &tensu1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            printf("请输入第二个矩阵第%d行第%d列的数： ", i+1 , j+1);
            scanf( "%d" , &tensu2[i][j]);
        }
    }

    /*calculate the result */

    for ( i = 0; i < 4 ; i++ ) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4 ; j++) {
            for(k = 0; k < 3 ;k++)
                tensu3[i][j] = tensu1 [i][k] * tensu2 [k][i] + tensu3[i][j];
        }
    }
    /* show result */
    printf("The first matrix is：\n");

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ) {
        putchar('|');
        for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
            printf( "%4d" , tensu1[i][j] );
        }
        putchar('|');
        putchar('\n');


    }

    printf("The second matrix is：\n");

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {
        putchar('|');
        for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
            printf( "%4d" , tensu1[i][j] );
        }
        putchar('|');
        putchar('\n');


    }

    printf("The result of matrix is：\n");

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ) {
        putchar('|');
        for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
            printf( " %4d " , tensu3[i][j] );
        }
        putchar('|');
        putchar('\n');


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited in your code.. Replace it.

/*calculate the result */

```
for ( i = 0; i < 4 ; i++ ) {
    for(j = 0; j < 4 ; j++) {
        tensu3[i][j] = 0;
        for(k = 0; k < 3 ;k++)
            tensu3[i][j] += tensu1 [i][j] * tensu2[k][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a variable a value before you use its value. You start using values from `tensu3` before you assign them values, so you are adding to whatever garbage values they happened to have.

Comment: Owing to your mention,I find where the problem is!I carelessly ignore that when I use the the code"tensu3[i][j] = tensu1 [i][k] * tensu2 [k][i] + tensu3[i][j]",I have already used the value...Thanks for your help!